# In Laravel Blade cant earn Object param

Tags: php, laravel, object, laravel-blade

In laravel blade I get an object, and write out {{ $ticket }}

```
{"id":1,
"program_id":1,
"title":"Di\u00e1k",
"price":200,
"created_at":"2019-02-27 15:20:07",
"updated_at":"2019-02-27 15:20:07",
"bought_tickets": {
   "id":3,
   "ticket_id":1,
   "event_id":6,
   "number":10,
   "created_at":"2019-02-28 13:41:51",
   "updated_at":"2019-02-28 13:41:51",
   "deleted_at":null}}
```

But if i want to write out the bought_tickets {{ $ticket->bought_tickets }} got nothing. It was as if it was not defined.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: `{{ }}` escapes and prints whatever is within it, so, if you are trying to output and object or an array, it will throw an error.

Comment: Try something `{{ $ticket->bought_tickets->id }}`

Comment: It looks like $ticket is in json format, so you need to use json_decode. You should not be able to print out objects like that.

Comment: {{ $ticket->bought_tickets->id }} throw error: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the model. I do a query:
Program::with('tickets', 'fields', 'tickets.boughtTickets')->get();

The relationship call method is boughtTickets not bought_tickets.